# Dom elements are not garbage collected when detaching event target's parent dom from within event listener

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, event-handling, google-chrome-devtools, circular-reference

**Question 1:** Why detached `dom` elements are not garbage collected in the following script

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>button {padding: 5px 10px;float: left;margin: 10px 5px;background-color: #4653eb;color: #fff;font-weight: bold;cursor: pointer;border: none;outline: none;}button:hover {background-color: #208c2c;}span {float:left;margin-right:2px}</style>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="show-btn">Show</button>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script src="js.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
// js.js
"use strict";
(function () {

    class Test {
        constructor(outerDom) {
            this._container = null;
            //this.onClick = null;
            this._init(outerDom);
        }

        _init(outerDom) {
            const container = document.createElement('div');

            const clearButton = container.appendChild(document.createElement('button'));
            clearButton.id = 'clear-btn';
            clearButton.textContent = 'Clear';

            //this.onClick = this._removeDomsOnClick.bind(this);
            //clearButton.addEventListener('click', this.onClick);
            clearButton.addEventListener('click', this._removeDomsOnClick.bind(this));

            for (var i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
                container.appendChild(document.createElement('span')).textContent = 'text inside span';
            };

            outerDom.textContent = '';
            outerDom.appendChild(container);
            this._container = container;
        }

        // Click event handler
        _removeDomsOnClick(e) {
            // Detaching event target from parent
            //e.target.parentNode.removeChild(e.target); // #1

            // Removing event listener
            //e.target.removeEventListener('click', this.onClick);
            //this.onClick = null;

            // Detaching clear button's parent node (It will remove clear button(ie event target) and 2000 spans)
            this._container.parentNode.removeChild(this._container);

            // Not needed(AFAIK). But making sure no reference kept.
            this._container = null;
        }
    }

    document.getElementById('show-btn').addEventListener('click', function () {
        // Not keeping any refernece to newly created instance
        new Test(document.getElementById('container'));
    });

}());
```

When click `button#show-btn`, it will create and attach a `dom` that contains `button#clear-btn` and 2000 `span` elements.

When click on `button#clear-btn`, it will detach previously added `dom` (which contains `button#clear-btn` (ie `e.target`) and 2000 `span` elements).

But these detached `doms` are not garbage collected (unless first detach `button#clear-btn` (ie `e.target`) from its parent). I can't see any reference to these `doms` in the script. Even though `event`  has reference to `target`, `path` etc, I expect it will garbage collect after click 
event finishes.

**Heap Snapshots & Allocation Timelines**

**1**
   Page just loaded.
   `button#clear-btn` and `span` elements are not created yet.
   
[heap:1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQdxc.png)

**2**
   After clicking `button#show-btn`
A parent `dom` that contain `button#clear-btn` and 2000 `span` elements is created and attached to visible `dom`
`50KB` memory assigned

[heap:2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09Pxr.png)

[timeline:2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuweL.png)

**3a**
 After clicking `button#clear-btn`.
    Previously created parent `dom` that containing `button#clear-btn` (ie `e.target`) and 2000 `span` elements is detached from visible `dom`. But they are **not garbage collected**.
`50KB` memory not released.

[heap:3a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ix5nK.png)

[timeline:3a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjPfF.png)

**3b**
    **Note:** First `button#clear-btn` (ie `e.target`) detached from parent `dom` (uncomment line #1).
 
    After clicking `button#clear-btn`.
    Previously created parent `dom` that containing `button#clear-btn` (ie `e.target`) and 2000 `span` elements is detached from visible `dom`. They are **garbage collected**.
`50KB` memory reduced to `10KB`.

[heap:3b](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zua04.png)

[timeline:3b](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FPPX.png)

**Question 2:** Even in `3b` why `10KB` is not released?
 Why `MouseEvent` object stays in memory. And so its parents `UIEvent`, `Event` etc. `globalThis in Window` holds it. What is it? Why it keep reference?
Also what is `this in system`?
[timeline:3bExpanded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrLQq.png)
(Answer to Q1 may be answer to this too)

**Question 3:** In `heap:1` why there are 6 `HTMLBodyElement` and 4 `CanvasRenderingContex2D` and 7 `HTMLDocument` and in `heap:2` why 9 `HTMLDivElement`
As page reloads, sometimes these numbers increases (26 `HTMLBodyElement`...?). I tried `Empty Cache and Hard Reload`. But no difference. If opened in new tab instead of reloading, these are back to normal.

In `3a`, I tried by removing event listener from `button#clear-btn` before detaching parent `dom` (Check comments in js file). But no difference.
I tried force `collect garbage` option. But detached doms are not collected.
Console is empty.
No breakpoints set.

`Chrome 78.0.3904.87 
 Chrome Canary 80.0.3959.0 
 Incognito Mode with no extensions`

Comment: Garbage collector won't kick in immediately. Sometimes it may take a lot of time until it does especially if you have a lot of RAM and not many tabs open. Or it could be a bug in Chrome...

Comment: @wOxxOm Only 4GB ram. Mostly I don't keep more than 5 tabs open at a time since my system will become too slow with chrome and vs code opened (maybe 5 tabs in vs code) :)